# Is there a standard accepted definition of in-situ quantification, and if so what is it?

Tags: semantics, formal-semantics, quantifiers

I'm reading a paper that references Montague being focused on in-situ quantification.  I'm not a linguist, so apologies for the naivety, but how does this differ from what is being called bounded quantification.

Also, what other types of possible quantification there are?

Any, or many, examples and explanations are welcome.

Comment: Which paper is it where you ran into this?

Comment: In situ quantification is contrasted with quantifier raising; in the latter analysis, quantifiers are moved to a different position on some none-surface level to get the semantics right, whereas in the former, quantifiers are evaluated in place without syntactic transformations being carried out.

Comment: Bound is usually opposed to free and occurs in the context of pronouns, which are formally represented as variables; quantification always binds variables, whereas free variables behave like third-person personal pronouns.

Comment: But to know better which distinction is meant here it would help if you could give a full reference.